# How can I load SQL data into python and then send to API

Tags: python, sql-server, python-requests, pyodbc

I am trying to load some preprocessed data in sqlserver to a web server using API through some python scripts.

Let's say that I have this data in the "product" table:

```
Product | Action | Response
------------------------------
a       |POST    | NULL
b       |PUT     | NULL
c       |DEL     | NULL
d       |POST    | NULL
e       |PUT     | NULL
f       |DEL     | NULL
```

To load the data from sqlserver I use this chunk of code which returns all rows from the 'query' result as a list:

```
import pyodbc

def queryresult(server, database, user, password, query):
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+user+';PWD='+password)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

So for this example I would have(I skip the Response column):

```
results = [(a, POST), (b, PUT), (c, DEL), (d, POST), (e, PUT), (f, DEL)]
```

Then, using requests module I would like to run:

- POST request for products a and d
- PUT for b and e
- DEL for c and f

and recieve the response, e.g.:

```
{'product_code':'a', 'response_code':'200'}
```

and update back column Response in the "product" table.

How would you do it? Should I create a class for products or run post requests directly from the list?
The biggest unknown here is how to divide products on 3 groups for 3 different requests.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have modul `urllib` or `requests` to send `HTTP` requests.

Comment: Hey, yeah I know those modules but I dont know how to send lets say 300 products using POST request, 100 products using PUT and delete 5 of them. All products are in one list.

Comment: you have to use `for` loop to send 300 requests POST, 100 requests PUT, and 5 requests DELETE.